# sample not working in sparkR session

Tags: r, apache-spark

I installed Spark-1.4.0 from source on my machine, running fedora 21, kernel 4.0.5-200.fc21.x86_64 and I ran install-dev.sh on
the spark-1.4.0/R directory. Now when I start 'sparkR' on my terminal everything starts up normally, I get to the command prompt and do the following :

```
> sample(seq(1,10),size=4)
Error in sample(seq(1, 10), size = 4) : unused argument (size = 4)
```

My question is why 'sample' throws this error in the SparkR console. This works in a regular R session, i.e.

```
> sample(seq(1,10),size=4)
[1]  1 10  4  2
```

Comment: I haven't tried `sparkR` yet, but maybe it masks the `sample` function with a different one? As a first debugging step, try just typing `sample` to see the source code, make sure it's coming from the `base` package and that it has the right parameters.

Comment: @daattali is correct there is a `SparkR::sample`. You can get the functionality you're looking for with `base::sample(seq(1,10),size=4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @daattali it was indeed masked. In a sparkR session I get :

```
> sample
nonstandardGenericFunction for "sample" defined from package "SparkR"

function (x, withReplacement, fraction, seed) 
{
    standardGeneric("sample")
}
<environment: 0x2e4c810>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, withReplacement, fraction, seed
Use  showMethods("sample")  for currently available ones.
>
```